Formula is currently double-counting a cell
I've got the following formula that looks for certain keywords in cells within a column.
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Data'!$G:$G,{"*" & Settings!$E$5 & "*","*" & Settings!$E$6 & "*","*" & Settings!$E$7 & "*"}))

Here is an example of the data on the Data sheet.



Column G




2024 September, 2024 August


2024 August


2024 May


2023 September


2024 September, 2024 August, 2023 May


2024 September, 2024 August, 2024 July



And the settings sheet.



3rd Quarter Months




2024 July


2024 August


2024 September



Using the above formula I get a count of occurrences for each of the months in the quarter. So I would get a count of 8. Instead, I need the count of cells that contains at least one of these months in the quarter. So the answer should be 4.
How can I achieve the count of cells that contain at least one of these months?
Edit: for the sake of simplicity I have trimmed this formula down to the problem area. I am using countifs as opposed to countif because I have other conditions that need to be met.


You may try (going with an assumption those'll are plain text formatted):
=countif(index(regexmatch(Data!G:G,join("|",Settings!E5:E7))),true)


Yes, they are plain text. This works very well. This is also less taxing than SUMPRODUCT, right?
